# WCF IIS configuration and Visual Studio 2010 debug configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, iis

I am trying to set up my WCF service (.svc) to work in Visual Studio 2010 (pressing F5 to debug), but also to have multiple configurations for each environments (DEV, QA, UAT &  Prod). When I originally built the WCF it was used purely in Visual Studio 2010 using .Net version 4 and debugging the service was easy enough by adding a WinForm application to pass in the values needed. When it was time to test the service on a server, I used the Publish feature to put the files on the DEV server and noticed that since it was using IIS that a web.config was created in the base directory.

So now that we are moving on to QA and UAT I need to make sure we have the configuration files for each environment as the Uri's change as well as various other values. Now after searching for a few days on Google, I have tried to use the XDT Transformations, but without having a third party add-in like SlowCheetah, this does not seem to work as it is only built for Web Applications. I have also tried to set up a post-build event to copy different configs:

```
copy "$(ProjectDir)Config\web.$(ConfigurationName).config" "$(ProjectDir)web.config" /Y
```

The copy process is set in the Build Events --> Post-build event command line textbox, however this does not seem to work when I use the publish method. I am ok with using multiple config files and copying them, I just have not had success with this.

The XDT makes the most sense to me and would be my preference if I could get it working. The main issue I am having is that it needs to work in Visual Studio, but also to work via IIS on the servers without having to go through a bunch of steps per environment. This is a company rule that I have to follow as well as not having a third party plug-in/add-in.

Is it possible to run the service in IIS and create a servicehost via code? I don't think it is as I believe the MSDN docs say that IIS creates it for you no matter what. Part of my reason wanting to do different configs is so that the page the user gets when they view the .svc file in the browser has the correct Uri in it not the machine name version.

TIA

**EDIT:** Setting up a dev web.config and including it in the project and then setting it to **Build Action: Content** fixes the copy method, so technically I have it working as long as I have completely different web.config files for each environment and an app.config for debugging (F5 in Visual Studio).